# liblinear one vs rest learn parameters

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

Liblinear (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) does not support for probability estimates.

Say I have three classes C1, C2 and C3.
I want to learn the model paramters for each 'one vs rest' cases:

```
           C1 vs C2&C3, 
           c2 vs C1&C3 and
           C3 vs C1&C2
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure? [Here](http://www.makelinux.net/man/1/L/liblinear-predict) it says that you can use the `-b` parameter for that.

Comment: I am talking bout http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/

Comment: So am I. [Version 1.93](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/liblinear.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear+zip), file predict.c, line 182: "-b probability_estimates: whether to output probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0); currently for logistic regression only\n"

Comment: yes. it supports only for logistic regression.

Comment: OK, so what do you need?

Comment: my problem is not a regression problem. mine is a classification problem.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, I know that libsvm also supports probability estimates, but I'm not sure if you can use that for your particular problem. Perhaps you should try asking this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ since you will find more expertise on this topic over there.

Comment: What model parameters do you want to learn?

Answer (score 0):

In lr, for -b 1 parameter, it actually not gives the p(c1) value. It give the

```
P(c1)=p(c1)/(p(c1)+p(c2)+p(c3))
```

in output file. So when you only have 1 class, it outputs 1.